# Is Chrome flag --app=http://localhost here to stay?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications

I am creating a HTML desktop app using Chrome that is starting from command line (Windows bat file) using this command `chrome.exe --app=http://localhost`. Flag `--app` starts Chrome window without home button and address bar. It looks like a desktop app. But I was wondering if Google will keep (support) this option since they stopped supporting Chrome apps (only working on Chromebooks)